# ExtJs. How to add items to a grid column header? (with modern theme)

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I would to add some items to grid column header.

It works with classic theme (using Ext.grid.Panel)

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s7u

but it does not work with modern theme (using Ext.grid.Grid)

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s7v

All items get to div with .x-gridcolumn.x-leaf .x-gridcolumn-body-el class with "display: none;" CSS style.

thanks

Comment: Just alter that style : .x-gridcolumn-body-el { display:block !important; }

Comment: @FabioBarros Thanks! It works for me. I will write full solution in separate comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a component to the target dom either on initialization or on rendering events of the grid.

```
 listeners: {
    initialize: function (grid) {
       var columns = grid.getColumns();
       columns.forEach(function(record){
       var targetDom = record.el.dom;
       var newPanel = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
         items: [{
           xtype: 'textfield'
         }],
         renderTo: targetDom
       });
      })
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fabio Barros

Solution is

```
 - add cls property to grid
 - add css rule with 'display: inline'

.grid-header-items .x-gridcolumn.x-leaf .x-gridcolumn-body-el {
  display: inline;
}//show items
.grid-header-items .x-gridcolumn .x-header-el {
  display: none;
}//hide header
        {
            xtype: 'grid',
            cls: 'grid-header-items',
            items: [
            .....
            ]
        }
```